# I can came back to first navigation control page with a button?

Tags: iphone, xcode, navigationcontroller

```
-(IBAction) btnReturn:(id) sender{

    firstView * firstview =[[firstView alloc]initWithNibName:@"firstView" bundle:nil];      
    [self.view pushViewController:firstview animated:NO];
}
```

with the previsly code I see the first view but the navigation control increment. I wold came bak as was the navigation starting point. Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pushViewController:animated:` will add to the navigation stack; you want `popViewControllerAnimated:` to go back one view in the stack.

If you want to return to the very first (root) view controller, you want `popToRootViewControllerAnimated:`.

See: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

In your above code you are pushing a *controller* on `self.view` (`firstView`, I am considering it as controller as you are creating it using `initWithNibName`: method, but you should you proper naming conventions to avoid confusions.) But view do not have any such method `pushViewController`:. Instead you sould use if you really have `self` (the controller in which you are using this `IBAction`) in *navigation stack*.

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:firstview animated:NO];
```

To pop controller from navigation stack, follow what ***@gregheo*** suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `popViewControllerAnimated` instead:

```
- (IBAction)btnReturn:(id)sender
{     
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO]; // Or Yes if you would like to have an animation.
}
```